# NVIDIA GPU support branch prediction? (with OpenACC)

Tags: cuda, nvidia, openacc

I'm using NVIDIA GPU with OpenACC
(NVIDIA GeForce960, compiler:PGI 15.7)

Does NVIDIA GPU support branch prediction?
My code has conditional execution code in long loop.  But when I run my code on GPU, It takes so long time.

Below is Example code .

```
#pragma acc parallel loop
for(i=0; i<1000; i++)  // NVIDIA GPU kernel with OpenACC
   for(j=0; j<1000; j++)
      if(a[i][j]==value)
         // do something...
      else if(a[i][j]==value2)
         // do another something...
      else
         // do another something...
```

If this code is compiled and run on CPU, CPU will do branch prediction for conditional execution loop.
Is NVIDIA GPU has same or similar skills like CPU's branch prediction?

If it has, how can I enable it?

Additional Question :

Is PGI 15.7 compiler can compile optimized code for GPU?
I know usual compilers(gcc... etc) can compile with optimizing skills, like changing conditional code execution order.

Comment: Current CUDA gpus do not support branch prediction. Probably instead of diving to such a low level, the thing you care about is "why is my code running slowly?" But nobody can answer that based on what you have posted.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Robert :)
What I really wanted know is 'Could CUDA gpu do branch prediction?'.
And if OK, Is there some switch to enable it.
But as you answered, now I know CUDA gpu has no branch prediction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is NVIDIA GPU has same or similar skills like CPU's branch prediction?

Current NVIDIA GPUs do not support branch prediction.

> Is PGI 15.7 compiler can compile optimized code for GPU?

Yes, the PGI tools have various kinds of optimization they can perform.  This is controlled at a high level with the `-Ox` command line switch (e.g. `-O3`), just like gcc/g++.  This optimization can occur during various phases of compilation, such as the conversion of OpenACC source to CUDA PTX, and the conversion of CUDA PTX to CUDA SASS.

Comment: Thanks for reply Robert :)
Than, with -O3 option, PGI compiler can re-ordering instructions to optimize conditional execution area? (i.e. if-else)
OpenACC spec doesn't have specific ways to indicate block and thread index like CUDA C, I can't remove branch divergence in 1 warp.
I think it occurs so many 'inactive' status threads, and slows my code.

Comment: FYI: the recommended compiler optimization flag for PGI compilers is `-fast`, which includes `-O2` and a lot of other, beneficial optimizations. You can also combine it with `-O3`, but I don't think I've ever seen `-O3 -fast` outperform just `-fast.`

Comment: Is there any way to restructure your code so that the branch statements happen outside of the innermost loop? It's generally the innermost loop that gets vectorized in OpenACC, so this is where you want to avoid divergence. If it can't be completely removed, sometimes it's possible to restructure the loop so that all of the true and false iterations are grouped together, so only one warp is actually divergent.

Comment: Thanks jeff :)
Unfortunately, I can't fix my whole code.  Because it's very long and complex code for image processing written by my co-worker(and I couldn't understand all of the contents).
So for fix code, I have to know which loops make many branch divergence.  Do you know some tools to find that things?

Comment: The nvidia profiling tools should cover that. NSight/Visual profiler should show it in a GUI. nvprof has the metrics `warp_execution_efficiency` and `warp_nonpred_execution_efficiency`.